# Check SCHTASKS Status in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have written a batch file with the following commands to check the schtasks status and I am planning to put this in a loop.

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('SCHTASKS /QUERY /S <servername> /FO LIST /TN "\MICROSOFT\deploy_db" ^| FIND /C "Running"') DO (IF %%I == 0 ( SET STATUS=Running) Else ( SET Status=Ready))
ECHO %%I
ECHO %STATUS%
```

But I am getting this following error:

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

If I write the following:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('SCHTASKS /QUERY /S <servername> /FO LIST /TN "\MICROSOFT\deploy_db" ^| FIND /C "Running"') DO 
(IF %%I == 0 ( SET STATUS=Running) Else ( SET Status=Ready))
ECHO %%I
ECHO %STATUS%
```

If I do the above the get the following:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

If I write the following:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('SCHTASKS /QUERY /S <servername> /FO LIST /TN "\MICROSOFT\deploy_db" ^| FIND /C "Running"') DO (IF %%I == 0 ( SET STATUS=Running) Else ( SET Status=Ready))
ECHO %STATUS%
```

If I do the above the get the following:

```
Running
```

Can anyone please help me with the script.

Comment: "*But I am getting this following error: ECHO is off.*" - that's not an error, it's what you get when you call `echo` with no parameters, it reports the status. You end the for loop at the end of the first line with `))` and `ECHO %%I` is outside the loop. The second one is incorrect because you have to `(` on the same line as `do`, not on the next line. You're also going to want to google `EnableDelayedExpansion` for your environment variables.

Comment: You know PowerShell can do `(Get-ScheduledTask 'deploy_db').State`, or `Get-ScheduledTask |Where State -eq Running`  right?

Comment: Am a noob to Powershell, how can I put it in Loop. Run a Schtask and keep checking till it is complete?

Comment: `Start-ScheduledTask 'whatever'; start-sleep -seconds 5; while ((Get-ScheduledTask 'whatever').state -eq Running) { start-sleep -seconds 5 }`

Comment: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-eq' operator.
At C:\resources\code\Test\Schtask_t.ps1:4 char:48
+ while ((Get-ScheduledTask 'whatever').state -eq <<<<  Running){ start-sleep -seconds 5 }  ... This is the error I get when I run the above command

Comment: Maybe you're on PS ancient edition and need to put Running in quotes `-eq "Running"`.  But that was just off the top of my head, it's not tested.

Answer (score 2):

You get the message `ECHO is off.` (or `on`) if you just type `echo` with nothing after it.  It's a sign that your variables are empty.

The variable `%%I` loses scope once you're out of the `DO` portion of `FOR`.  I also had problems getting the line to run if I didn't supply the full path to schtasks.

This works for me:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /QUERY /S <servername> /FO LIST /TN "\MICROSOFT\deploy_db" ^| FIND /C "Running"') DO (
    IF %%I == 0 (SET STATUS=Running) Else (SET Status=Ready)
    ECHO %%I
)
ECHO %STATUS%
```

If you're in a loop, you may have problems with STATUS updating.  If so, try:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%I IN ('C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /QUERY /S <servername> /FO LIST /TN "\MICROSOFT\deploy_db" ^| FIND /C "Running"') DO (
    IF %%I == 0 (SET STATUS=Running) Else (SET Status=Ready)
    ECHO %%I
)
ECHO !STATUS!
```